# Difference between SM-Noop and nothing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso#noopssosessionprovider
say "As the name dictates, this provider does nothing. This provider can be used for suppressing SSO behavior for a specific technical profile."

What is the difference between invoking SM-Noop at a given location in the custom policy and a situation where I would not invoke it at that same location?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SM-Noop explicitly states to not include the technical profile as part of the session. If session management technical profile reference is absent from a technical profile, the result should be the same, but better to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you Jas Suri. Do you mean that you want to make sure there is not inheritence in the calls among technical profiles? I also have a related question, here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343986/removing-sm-aad-for-cookie-authentication , if you have time.

Comment: What does this mean "not include the technical profile as part of the session"? Are we saying that the output claims won't be apart of the session token?

Comment: This article explains how this works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso